# QTreeWidgetItem hide child checkboxes but not parent checkboxes

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qtreewidget, qtreewidgetitem

I have a QTreeWidget with two levels.  Parent level is first and child level underneath.  I want the parent level to contain checkboxes, but I want the children to have no checkboxes.  In the following example, every QTreeWidgetItem shows a checkbox.  If I remove "child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)" then ALL checkboxes disappear, not just the child checkboxes.

How can I hide the child checkboxes, but not the parent checkboxes?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
import sys

def main(): 
    app        = QApplication (sys.argv)
    tree       = QTreeWidget ()
    headerItem = QTreeWidgetItem()
    item       = QTreeWidgetItem()

    for i in xrange(2):
        parent = QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
        parent.setText(0, "Parent {}".format(i))
        parent.setFlags(parent.flags() | Qt.ItemIsTristate | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        parent.setExpanded(True)
        parent.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        for x in xrange(3):
            child = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
            child.setFlags(child.flags() & ~(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable))
            child.setText(0, "Child {}".format(x))
            #child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
    tree.show() 
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here "child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)" -- does mean that "**you are setting checkbox to column "0" with unchecked state**".

**Now revisit your code:**

you are not setting it for parent which you want so do something like below:

**set checkbox for parent item:**

```
parent.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
```

**Remove below code completely** as it sets checkboxes for child which you do not want

```
child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
```

**Also Delete the flags setting, as we noticed setting flags to parent, are carried to child items.**

The code Roughly looks somewhat like this in first for loop:

```
        parent = QTreeWidgetItem(tree)
        parent.setText(0, "Parent {}".format(i))
        parent.setExpanded(True)
        parent.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)
        for x in xrange(3):
            child = QTreeWidgetItem(parent)
            child.setText(0, "Child {}".format(x))
```

Comment: Good catch.  My example code did not match my real code.  I've added your suggestion and m7913d's suggestion to my example above.  Unfortunately the child checkbox is still visible.

Comment: did you completely remove the code "child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)"

Comment: I still see this  "child.setCheckState(0, Qt.Unchecked)" in your code. Please remove it completely

Comment: If I do that, I get no checkboxes.  Neither parent or child.  Even if leave the setCheckState for parent.

Comment: I tried in Cplusplus. it is working. But i did not set flags. Could you please comment out  flags statement in both parent and child and give a try?

Comment: Fantastic! That did the trick!  Thanks.  Could you update your answer to include this.. I'm giving your answer the check.

Comment: Done. Updated the answer. Please review it.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the the flag `ItemIsUserChechable` and `ItemIsSelectable` from your child [flags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html) instead of adding them:

```
child.setFlags(child.flags() & ~(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable))
```

I would also expect that you shouldn't set the checkState of the child, but that of the parent.
See the [python documentation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) for more information about binary operations.

Comment: Good catch.  My example code did not match my real code.  I've added your suggestion and pavanc's suggestion to my example above.  Unfortunately the child checkbox is still visible.  Your suggestion prevents me from checking it, but it doesn't hide the checkbox itself.